# Sum records in one table and check if equal in second

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have a bit complicated (for me) issue that I need to solve. I have 2 `SQL` tables - `Payments` and `Clients`.

In table `Clients` I have few columns but most important are `totalPaid` and `clientID`.

In `Payments` there columns called `clientID` and `amountPaid` the issue is that there may be many records for one `clintID` in `Payments`.

Now I need to find out whether for every SUM(amountPaid) FROM Payments is the value in Clients (totalPaid) equal.

I'm sorry for posting question without code-providing but may someone be so kind helping me?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the results that match:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Clients C
INNER JOIN (SELECT ClientID, SUM(amountPaid) AmountPaid
            FROM Payments
            GROUP BY ClientID) P
    ON C.ClientID = P.ClientID
WHERE C.TotalPaid = P.AmountPaid
```

To find the results that don't match:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Clients C
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ClientID, SUM(amountPaid) AmountPaid
            FROM Payments
            GROUP BY ClientID) P
    ON C.ClientID = P.ClientID
WHERE C.TotalPaid <> ISNULL(P.AmountPaid,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you what want

```
select clientId
, case when totalPaid = isnull(TotalAmount, 0) then 'yes' else 'no' AreEqual
from Clients left join 
(select clientid id, sum(amountPaid) TotalAmount
from payments
group by clientid) temp on clientid = id
```

This will prevent recurrence of the problem.

```
alter table clients
drop column totalPaid
```